# Excluding method names when validating a slug in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I wonder how can I validate a slug (from user input) against all method names of a controller (not necessarily the ones in `self`) other than hardcode it, so say `tag/tomato` is valid, but `/tag/all` is not, because there is an `all` method in controller `Tag`? Using reflection?

Or there is a better practice?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you really want to protect against routing conflicts and that is only loosely connected to the method names in your controller.

You can get all the routes at run time from

```
Rails.application.routes.routes
```

That gives you an Array of `ActionDispatch::Routing::Route` instances. Then, to get the GET routes:

```
gettable = Rails.application.routes.routes.select do |r|
    r.verb == 'GET' || r.verb == '' # Watch out for "no verb" -> "all verbs"
end
```

and from there you can extract the paths and check that your tag doesn't match any of them:

```
paths = Rails.application.routes.routes.
        select { |r| r.verb == 'GET' || r.verb == '' }.
        map    { |r| r.path                          }
```

That leaves you with a list of `/this/:that(.:format)` style paths in `paths`.

Once all of that is in place, you'll want an application initializer to check that you haven't added any routes to the `/tag/` namespace that happen to match the current state of the tag database; otherwise, conflicts can creep in during development.

That should convince you that you're better off keeping the normal routes for creating, viewing, and such in a separate namespace from your human/SEO friendly `/tag/pancakes` routes. You could leave the usual ones in `/tag` but move the friendly ones to `/taxonomy/`, `/category/`, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of methods defined in your controller like this:

```
TagController.instance_methods(false)
```

Note that by passing `false` as an argument to `instance_methods`, you get the list of methods that are *not* inherited.